# .NET app can't find a node_modules directory in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

My .NET application keeps showing that a particular node_modules directory doesn't exist on our Linux servers.  The code finds it on my local Windows machine and on my private Linux server, and I've confirmed on the CI/CD script that the directory exists and everyone has full control. I'm guessing it's some kind of permissions issue, but I'm not sure how to confirm.

I don't have direct access to the server, but I've confirmed in the CI/CD pipeline's deployment script that the directory exists and I set the permissions with:

```
chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/node_modules/mydirectory
```

and confirmed the permissions with:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/node_modules
```

as:

```
drwxrwxrwx 9 root root 4096 Aug 23 21:41 mydirectory
```

Shouldn't this be more than enough permissions for a Directory.Exists?

However, in the C# code Directory.Exists always returns false.

In the code I've tried:

```
$"{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{Path.Combine("usr", "lib", "node_modules", "mydirectory")}
```

which outputs in the server log as:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/mydirectory
```

and I've tried

```
Path.GetFullPath(path)
```

which outputs in the server log as:

```
/home/vcap/app/usr/lib/node_modules/mydirectory
```

Neither versions of the code return true for Directory.Exists.

I also tried installing the node module in the application folder instead of "npm install -g" with:

```
cd src/Applications/MyApp
npm root
```

Which gave me a path of:

```
/builds/blah/blah/src/Applications/MyApp/node_modules
```

Then I ran:

```
npm install mydirectory
```

And confirmed it was there with:

```
ls -l /builds/blah/blah/src/Applications/MyApp/node_modules
```

And got:

```
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root 4096 Aug 24 15:08 mydirectory
```

And in the code I tried:

```
var path = Path.Combine("/builds/blah/blah/src/Applications/MyApp/node_modules", "mydirectory");
```

Finally, I ran `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and found my app was running in:

```
/home/vcap/app
```

That directory doesn't exist when I run the deploy script so I created it and installed the npm package with:

```
mkdir -p /home/vcap/app
cd /home/vcap/app
npm install mydirectory
```

I blasted it with everyone-full-control:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/vcap/app/node_modules/mydirectory
```

Confirmed it exists and has permissions with `ls -l`, which resulted in:

```
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root 4096 Aug 24 19:53 mydirectory
```

Changed my code to point to the new location:

```
var path = Path.Combine("/home/vcap/app/node_modules", "mydirectory");
```

And `Directory.Exists(path)` still returns `false`.

I've confirmed that my code can see the temp directory (`/home/vcap/tmp`) and save and see files in that directory.

Any ideas of how to get .NET to see a node_modules directory on the Linux server?  Is there some kind of security block on accessing any folder or file outside of the temp directory, how would I confirm this?

Comment: Why are you deploying `node_modules` to production? Also, why are you using `/usr/lib/node_modules` instead of an application-scoped `node_modules` directory? Methinks that's asking for trouble...

Comment: `usr/lib/node_modules/mydirectory` and `/usr/lib/node_modules/mydirectory` are not equivalent. (The former is not an absolute path: it's a path relative to your processes' current working directory)

Comment: @Dai Thanks, I updated the question with /usr and how I tried installing the npm module in the app directory (but the code still says the directory doesnt exist for both tries)

Comment: Please post the **entire statement** where you print the `Path.Combine` result - right now all you're showing us is a formattable string expression (and the `$"` part is unnecessary as you're just using the return-value of `Combine` verbatim). If possible please show your entire method. Also print `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and `Environment.UserName` too.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the tip about Environment.CurrentDirectory and I changed everything to point to that directory, but it didn't seem to work.  I posted my results in the question.